# How to join two matrix with different dimensions?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have two matrices with different dimensions I want to join them together in one matrix.
for example, I have two lists of diseases associated with their symptoms in both matrix, what I want is to join these two lists or matrix in one matrix without lost the observation in each original matrix.

```
list1 = {{"Dis", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"},
         {"D1", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {"D2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D3", 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
         {"D4", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {"D5", 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {"D6", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
         {"D7", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
List2 = {{"Dis", "S7", "S8", "S4", "S9", "S10", "S3", "S11", "S12", "S5", "S1"},
         {"D2", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {"D8", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         {"D9", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {"D10", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         {"D6", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D11", 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
         {"D12", 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D13", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
         {"D14", 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {"D15", 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         {"D16", 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {"D17", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

in order to get output like that:

```
{{"Dis", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", 
  "S11", "S12"}, {"D1", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D2", 1,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {"D3", 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {"D4", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D5", 1, 1, 
  1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D6", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  0, 1}, {"D7", 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D8", 1, 1, 1, 
  1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {"D9", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
  1}, {"D10", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"D6", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D11", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {"D12", 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"D13", 1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0, 1, 0, 0}, {"D14", 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {"D15", 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {"D16", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 0}, {"D17", 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

thank you for any insight

Comment: Can you explain a little better what exact operation you are trying to do? I don't understand what way you would like to combine this data.

Comment: Significantly related (possible duplicates?) by same user: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195340/matrics-manipulations and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194840/confusion-matrix-using-data-from-two-matrices.

Comment: for example, I have two lists of disease related to their symptoms in both matrix , what i want is to join this two lists or matrix in one matrix without lost the observation in each original matrix

Comment: OK, but this doesn't yet explain how to merge these datasets. Can you explain how you would do it "on paper", step-by-step? (Preferably, edit your question with these details)

Comment: that is my question if there is way in Mathematica to merge them

Comment: Are the questions not related? The extra context from your past questions might help future answerers, since this question doesn't have a lot of detail in it. Further - I'm sure there is a way to do what you're looking for, but it's difficult for me to understand _precisely what_ it is you're looking for. Perhaps another user will be able to help.

Comment: thank you carl Lange

Comment: Do you mean to sum the values where they overlap? For example row D6 col S1 is 1 in both list1 and list2. In the combined matrix, should that position be 2?

Comment: exactly MelaGo that is what i want do you have any idea

Comment: This is a non-traditional math.

Comment: how? @user64494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the first thing I came up with, but unfortunately it's a little gross, and I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. I'm afraid I can't spend more time on this question so hopefully someone else can flesh this out.

First let's transform the data into `Dataset`s. This conversion is only the first gross part.

```
d1 = ImportString[ExportString[list1, "CSV"], "Dataset", 
  HeaderLines -> {1, 1}]
d2 = ImportString[ExportString[list2, "CSV"], "Dataset", 
  HeaderLines -> {1, 1}]
```

and now we can join the data:

```
Join[d1, d2]
```

[image]

We can replace the Missing values with 0 like so:

```
d = Transpose@Transpose@Join[d1, d2] /. _Missing -> 0
```

[image]

(We must `Transpose` so that the underlying `Association` actually has the `Missing` values to replace, rather than just short `Association`s. Check out the `Normal` of the dataset to see what I mean.)

You can convert back to your original structure with:

```
ImportString[ExportString[d, "CSV"], "CSV"]
```

> ```
> {{"", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", 
>   "S11", "S12"}, {"D1", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D2", 0,
>    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {"D3", 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>    0, 0, 0}, {"D4", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D5", 1, 1, 
>   1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D6", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
>   1, 0}, {"D7", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D8", 0, 0, 0, 
>   1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {"D9", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
>   1}, {"D10", 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {"D11", 1, 0, 1, 0,
>    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D12", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
>   0}, {"D13", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {"D14", 1, 0, 0, 1,
>    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {"D15", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
>   0}, {"D16", 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {"D17", 0, 0, 0, 1,
>    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

This answer contains a lot of bad code and I would recommend someone else add a better answer.

Comment: Carl that so helpfull need only all the col {} empty replaced by 0 thank you so much

Comment: @BenAawf See my edit.

Comment: thank you so much, #Carl Lange for your insight but this output does not help as a matrix.

Comment: @BenAawf See my edit.